# Deleting Duplicate Array Entries

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a Scanner to read in a text file with fraction Strings of the form "a/b", store them in an array, then print to the console each unique one along with its count. I can print each separate entry in the text file with an accurate count, but I can't figure out how to print the contents of the array without any duplicates.

I'm also trying to accomplish this entirely within main. Here's what I've got so far:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

        ArrayList<String> fracs = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> fracsDisplay = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(input.hasNext())
            fracs.add(input.next());

        for(int i = 0; i < fracs.size(); i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < fracs.size(); j++)
            {
                if(fracs.get(i).equals(fracs.get(j)))
                    count++;
            }
            System.out.println(fracs.get(i) + ": " + count);
        }

        input.close();
}
```

Comment: hmm, you could before adding the elements check for `fracs.contains(...)` if the array contains already an element and if so just increment the counter or avoid adding the element again. A `Set` is preventing duplicate entries by default. And why don't you use a `Map` if you want to print the entry-name as well as its count? Lookup the count (=value) via the unique entry (=key)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get rid of duplicates would be to use a `Set`, as you are storing Strings duplicates won't be added.

Instead of `ArrayList<String> fracsDisplay = new ArrayList<String>();` you could use:

```
Set<String> fracsDisplay = new HashSet<>();
fracsDisplay.addAll(fracs);
for (String s : fracsDisplay) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

if some kind of order needs to be maintained then I would suggest a `TreeSet`, but either will handle the removal of duplicates... which seems to be what you want in this case.

Comment: disadvantage if the entries should be available in an ordered structure

Comment: True, in this case a `TreeSet` could be used, OP didn't state whether order was important or not... answer updated to reflect your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If a grasp it, this task is a **"Word Count"-like task**. To do such a task, HashMap is the best choice.
I suggest you use a **HashMap** to do this task. Your algorithm has a O(n^2) time complexity. You can use a HashMap to reduce it down to O(n). Using a HashMap also helps you deduplicate. Hava a try.

```
        HashMap<String, Integer> fracs = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            String frac = input.next();
            if (! fracs.containsKey(frac)) {
                fracs.put(frac, 1);
            } else {
                fracs.put(frac, fracs.get(frac) + 1);
            }
        }

        input.close();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> fracCount : fracs.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(fracCount.getKey() + " " + fracCount.getValue());
        }
```

If fraction strings should keep the order of occurance, use **LinkedHashMap**; If fraction String should keep the lexicographical order, or some spercific order, use **SortedHashMap**. Here I suggest you read "**Java Generics and Collections**" which focus on **Java Collection framework**.

Answer (score 0):

Should you store everything into an ArrayList? You could use either a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) since dublications there are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet` as `Set` collection will not allow duplicate values. If your order of array is important then you can use `LinkedHashSet`.

```
Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
Collections.addAll(set, array);
```